# Can we identify image having any overlay using quartz?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, quartz-graphics

I have to work with image which is coming from some server. We want to process that image so that we can find out does it contain any specific color region.

Is there any way so that the image coming from server will be overlaid image & on device side we can process it to check if it contains those overlays?

I have never being worked on quartz stuff. If anybody can suggest some other solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this depending on how complex you wish to get. OpenCV has image blocking which can segregate images into distinct regions. Or check out [Image tools](http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/) especially blob extraction and then look at the general pixel colouration in a single blob.